# Symfony no me coge bien la RUTA

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, annotation

Estoy empezando un proyecto en symfony 4 y tengo un problema con las rutas.
Estoy usando `annotations`

Este es mi `IndexController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;


/**
 * Class IndexController
 *
 * @Route('/index')
 */
class IndexController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('index/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'IndexController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Y este es el error que me da:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo instalados también `annotations` y `routing` con lo cual debería funcionar pero no lo hace.

Comment: peoro tu ruta esta  en el home del proyecto "/" no esta en "/index" deberias acceder solo poniendo la pleca

Comment: sale el mismo error que poniendo index

Comment: como tienes tu routin.yml?

Comment: No sé a qué se debía el error, pero como estaba empezando, borré el proyecto y lo empecé de 0 y me funcionó, el routing.yml está completamente comentado pues uso las rutas en las anotaciones

Comment: Pdrias enseñarnos la ruta que pusiste en tu navegador. Quedó solucionado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En algunas ocasiones me ha sucedido algo similar y resulta que son los `name` que le pones a las rutas, si coinciden **Symfony** solo toma el primero.

Te propongo lo siguiente

```
/**
 * Class IndexController
 *
 * @Route('/index')
 */
class IndexController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="app_index")
     *                      ^^Agrégale otro nombre a la ruta
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('index/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'IndexController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que tienes este código en tu routes.yaml en el directorio config.

```
controller:
     resource: "../src/Controller"
     type: annotation
```

Answer (score 0):

Reemplaza éste código:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
```

por éste:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
```

Comment: por qué? recuerda no solo poner código sino además explicarlo

Comment: Porque así lo recomienda Symfony. [https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html]

Comment: Pues eso va en la respuesta